# Querying a document in MongoDB without discriminator

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Suppose I create a document in a MongoDB collection with the following structure and command:

```
db.foo.insert(
    {
        "PatientCore" :
        { "Name" : "John Doe", "Age" : 30 },
        "OnArrivalData" :
        {
            "Readings" :
            { "Temperature" : 100.1, "HBP" : 140, "LBP" : 88, "TimeStamp" : new Date() },
            "Attending Doctor" : "Dr. Samuel John"
        },
        "TreatmentStage" :
        [
            {
                "StageName" : "Surgery",
                "Readings" :
                [
                    { "Temperature" : 100.1, "HBP" : 130, "LBP" : 70, "TimeStamp" : new Date() },
                    { "Temperature" : 99.1, "HBP" : 120, "LBP" : 70, "TimeStamp" : new Date() 
                ],
            },
            {
                "StageName" : "ICU",
                "Readings" :
                [
                    { "Temperature" : 99, "HBP" : 135, "LBP" : 72, "TimeStamp" : new Date() },
                    { "Temperature" : 98.6, "HBP" : 141, "LBP" : 80, "TimeStamp" : new Date() }
                ],
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

Firstly, please note that I have multiple occurrences of "Readings" in the document.

I want to query "Readings" across the document in such a way that I don't have to qualify it with the reference to the embedded document. How can I achieve this? We can assume that the structure of "Readings" will be consistent.

I know that I can also work towards re-structuring the document, but here I don't have the liberty to do so.

Comment: What does "I want to query "Readings" across the document in such a way that I don't have to qualify it with the reference to the embedded document" mean? It's usually more practical to add an example if what values you have to query with and what should come out, especially for non english speakers.

Comment: @RemonvanVliet: I think he wants to say something like `*.Readings` rather than `OnArrivalData.Readings` and `TreatmentStage.Readings` explicitly.

Comment: You may have observed that a key named "Readings" appears thrice in the document. I want to query the document in such a way that every instance of "Readings" key is returned, regardless of it's positioning in the document. I hope this time I am clear enough.

Comment: @mu Ah, not possible in that case ;)

Comment: @Kabeer Yes it is. I'm one of those people that are not native english speakers so I had trouble understanding what you were asking. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is currently not possible as it would require MongoDB to understand field name wildcards. It would have to allow things like `{'*.Readings.Temperature': 99}` which it does not at time of writing.

Ther feature request is here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-267